# How can I export a filtered SharePoint list using only OotB options?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

I'm currently working in SharePoint 2010 and additional features are locked down, in that 3rd party web parts and such are not allowed. I'd like to request help using Out-of-the-Box solutions...

My current issue is as follows:

I have a list where one column will be used for filtering

The column to be filtered contains many unique values, and creating views for each entry is out of the question

The list needs to be exported from Datasheet view with only the rows containing the filtered data into an Excel spreadsheet (currently all data in the list is exported regardless of my attempts at filtering)

As stated above, I cannot make use of 3rd party solutions or custom components

The situation seems pretty grim, since recent searches on the subject show that SP 2010 simply doesn't support filtered exports. Any guidance or suggestions on how to make this work would be **highly** appreciated.

Edit: In response to teylyn, the need to export from SharePoint stems from having remote sites with differing levels of access, making a shared Excel doc a non-viable option. I'd resort to views, but there are so many different possible items to filter with, creating a view for each one would be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to explain the need to export the data. Regardless of that, you have basically two options that don't involve managed code in Sharepoint:

1. You can build a view with a filter in the view definition (using the GUI) and only the records showing in the SharepPoint view will be exported to Excel.
2. Excel is one of the most powerful software packages out there. It would be far easier to export all the data into Excel and then build a filtering system in Excel to show only specific records.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I'll add that to the question.